# Handle multiple WebSocket connections

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, p2p

I'm making some tests using WebSocket, and I trying to communicate with various "peers" like a P2P network.

I tried this solution below, it works to open all conections and handle all data, but I can't reply to "peer" that I received the initial message.

Anynone have a better idea or other solution? Thanks!

```
var WebSocket = require('ws');
var peers = ['ws://127.0.0.1:1001', 'ws://127.0.0.1:1002', 'ws://127.0.0.1:1003'];
var ws = [];

for(var i = 0; i<peers.length; i++){
    ws[i] = new WebSocket(peers[i]);
    ws[i].on('open', function open() {
        ws[i].send('something');
    });
    ws[i].on('message', function(data, flags) {
        console.log(data);
    });

    ws[i].on('error', function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Output:

```
 "Cannot read property 'send' of undefined"
```

Comment: I'm am fairly confident the duplicate I've linked to should thoroughly answer your question; please let me know if you don't agree.

Comment: It's similar problem, but I still get the same error.

"Cannot read property 'send' of undefined"

Comment: Now working! Thanks!